# Getting 404 error in IIS when calling asp page

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with my asp.net 4.0 application. When I call it on the server, it works, but when I call it from outside the server, it gives me a 404 error.

The link I call the asp.net application from is the good one. Other asp.net 4.0 applications are working fine when called from outside the server. The other applications are in another folder though, but I do not see why it would work under a folder and not another one. There is no IP restrictions on the applications.

Anyone got that error int eh past?

Thanks

EDIT:
The app is configured as an asp.net 4.0 application. it is stored in a virtual directory.

This link works:
http://localhost/Phonebook/PhoneBook/default-defaut.aspx

this link does not : https://www.test.com/Phonebook/PhoneBook/default-defaut.aspx

Comment: Did you configure your app as a Virtual Directory or as an Application in IIS?

Comment: @icarus updated the thread with answers

Comment: @Adam tuliper updated thread with answers to your questions

Comment: Hum.... why are you using https on your external link? Is it enabled on your Virtual Directory? You probably need to enable https on your new website. What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Question: does any other application in your local machine work with that kind of external link? According to your description, cause can be anything. You have to narrow it down one by one.

Comment: @Icarus it is the custom 404 error that who ever setted up teh server did.

Comment: @Sheen, yes they are other apps taht works using https, but they are under another folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker and me found the answer. It's because the server I called on my url was supposed to have a rule redirecting the browser to the right url. So IIS7 on my test server was setted up right.

Answer (score 0):

Theres several things to check.

1. That test.com is even going to your server. Put a file in the root directory 'test.txt' that IIS lists as the root folder for your site. ensure you can get to it.
2. Once you verify your root site folder WORKS for ex., www.test.com/test.txt then ensure you have a virtual directory /phonebook that contains a folder phonebook within it.

Seems overkill to be having to folders named phonebook. Try taking one of them out and pointing your web application to your

c:\whatever\phonebook\phonebook folder.

Comment: test.com is a dummy site for the example, that is not the real name of the domain. I tried the txt file trick and it work when it was on the root.

Comment: I do have a phonebook that contains a folder phonebook. It might be overkill, but when I was trying to find a solution, some one said they had a bug with apps on teh root, so I tried to remove this from teh equation.

Comment: @Hugo did you try txt file trick in the application folder? I mean put the txt file in the virtual directory of the application and see if you can get to it.

Comment: ok so how is IIS setup from your root? when you open IIS do you have a virtual directory at the root? How have you pointed IIS to your folder? having an app at the root folder is no issue and believe me.. we're aware that test.com is not your real site : )

Comment: @sheen yes, it did not work (got a 404 like when I was calling my app). It seems the folder is somehow blocked, how could I unblock the folder??

Comment: I have the website that is linked to my root. Under it, I have many virtual directorys and applications (some are on the root, some are under virtual directorys)

Comment: @Adam tuliper To point IIS to my folder, I simply created a new virtual folder and when IIS ask for hte physical path, I gave it the physical path of Phonebook (which is located under the the root both on the physical side and virtual side) and sorry, I think I misunderstood your first thing to try on the answer, lol

Comment: In that case, can you see folder's permission and make sure IUSR is included?

Comment: @Sheen, the group IIS_IUsrs has rights to it. The user IUSR does not but I do not use it. In my auntehntication feature, I use the application pool instead of teh default user.

Comment: if iuser was an issue youd get unauthorized not a 404. the folder itself wouldn't yield a 404. create a new virtual directory named app1 and point it to the folder just ONE level  _above_ your bin folder. so if its  ...phoneapp/phoneapp/bin point it to ...phoneapp/phoneapp.  Then place a text file here and try to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure port 443 is bound to your app if you're using https, that could be your problem.

Comment: That generally wouldn't be the cause a 404 on iis.